# Github inside settings I have no options

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I joined a company repository when I open the 'Settings' page there are no options such as,
Environments, Secrets, Actions and etc.
I think it is related to permissions but I am not sure.
Does anyone come across this situation?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-roles-for-an-organization)

Read this doc to learn more about roles and permissions for organizations' repositories, and to simply answer your question, yes it is related to permissions.